# Does "for almost each object" make sense in this example?

Tags: algorithmic-randomness

In the 2nd paragraph at [Kolmogorov complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity), these is the following sentence.

"In particular, **for almost each object** it is not possible to compute even a lower bound for its Kolmogorov complexity ..."

Does **for almost each object** have a particular mathematical meaning. Am I missing something, this does not appear to me, to be good English grammar, in the context where it is used?

Comment: That article seems really atypical for Wikipedia. In particular it makes lots of unsupported claims; I'm surprised not to see [citation needed] all over the place -- including the sentence you point out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are right about the grammar. The appropriate mathematical phrase would be "for almost every object" or even better, "almost all objects". So I suggest you edit the wikipedia page to make the change..

"Almost all" has a precise meaning you don't need to know to get the grammar right. For example, almost all real numbers are irrational.

**Edit:** Noting the comment from @dbx , I wonder whether it's worth fixing grammar on a page that seems to need a lot more fixing.

Comment: thanks for that feedback @Ethan